# Material UI - Multiple makeStyles or one

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am not sure what the correct approach here is. Is it ok if I create styles with makeStyles per component or should I create one in the base component and pass down class names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is better to create the styles in their respective components. It'll be more manageable as all the styles don't sit in one place and will not become a huge file. Also passing down styles for each component from their parent component will create the issue of [prop-drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling).
If you've some general common styles then add them to the theme file which will be more maintainable and easy to debug.
Another way to manage common styles to create makeStyles hook of common styles in a separate file and then import that hook and use it in the component wherever needed instead of passing through the prop.

Comment: Thank you very much! So sorry there is no performance issues with having many makeStyles in your app?

Comment: I guess no. As in this scenario, all the styles are not loaded at once instead loaded as required.